# ReportViewer databinding (WPF)

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, xsd, datasource

I have a rdlc file and I try to show it using report viewer control in WPF. My DataSource is called 'OfficeDataSet' and DataSet used in report is called 'Address'. I try to initialize report viewer (I put it in WindowsFormsHost) like this:

```
 private void PrepareReport()
    {
        reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        officeDataSet = new OfficeDataSet();            
        adapter = new AddressTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(officeDataSet.Address);

        reportDataSource.Name = "OfficeDataSet_Address";
        reportDataSource.Value = officeDataSet.Address;
        viewerInstance.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        viewerInstance.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WpfApplication1.Reports.TestReport.rdlc";
        viewerInstance.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);

        viewerInstance.RefreshReport();
    }
```

but I got the message "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'Address'".
Anybody know what can be wrong with this code? (I'm totally new in WPF and Reporting Services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember well, the datasource into the report file should have the same name (or maybe value) as the reportDataSource. So in your report file the datasource should be called "OfficeDataSet_Address".